# How to upload and store multiple images in Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin-coroutines

In my project, I'm trying to upload multiple images to Firebase storage and storing the downloaded url of images to firebase database. Here is my code

```
suspend fun uploadData(dataMap: HashMap<String, String>, imagePaths: Array<Uri?>){
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
            dataMap["selfie"] =getUrlForGallery(imagePaths[0])
            dataMap["adhaar pic"] = getUrlForCamera(imagePaths[1])
                dbReference.collection("Users Data").document(firebaseAuth.currentUser?.uid!!)  // Not working properly
                    .set(dataMap).addOnCompleteListener {
                        uploadResponse.postValue("success")
                    }
        }
}

private suspend fun getUrlForGallery(imagePaths : Uri?) =
    suspendCoroutine<String> {continuation ->
        val reference =
            storageReference.reference.child("images/${firebaseAuth.currentUser?.uid}/")
                .child("gallery")
        reference.putFile(imagePaths!!)
            .addOnSuccessListener {

                reference.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener {

                    continuation.resume(it.toString())
                }
            }
    }

private suspend fun getUrlForCamera(imagePaths : Uri?) =
    suspendCoroutine<String> {continuation ->
        val reference =
            storageReference.reference.child("images/${firebaseAuth.currentUser?.uid}/")
                .child("camera")
        reference.putFile(imagePaths!!)
            .addOnSuccessListener {

                reference.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener {

                continuation.resume(it.toString())
                }
            }
    }
```

**Edited : My Project level gradle is :-**

```
  buildscript {
   ext.kotlin_version = "1.4.21"
    repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
 }
 dependencies {
    def nav_version = "2.3.1"
    def koin_version = "2.1.5"
    classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.4.1'
    classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle- plugin:$nav_version"
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
    classpath "org.koin:koin-gradle-plugin:$koin_version"
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
  repositories {
     google()
     jcenter()
     maven { url "https://oss.jfrog.org/libs-snapshot" }
     maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
     }
  }
 }

task clean(type: Delete) {
 delete rootProject.buildDir
 }
```

**My App level gradle is :-**

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
 apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
 apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
 apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
 apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs"
 apply plugin: 'koin'
 apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'

 android {
  compileSdkVersion 29
  buildToolsVersion "30.0.1"

   defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.sarim.zomato"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        debuggable false
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug {
        debuggable true
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    targetCompatibility = 1.8
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
buildFeatures{
    dataBinding = true
    viewBinding = true
}
}

dependencies {
def nav_version = "2.3.2"
def koin_version = "2.1.5"
implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'


//Kotlin Coroutines
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.4.0"
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.4.0"


//ViewModel and LiveData
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0"

//Material Design dependency
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0-beta01'

//Android Navigation Dependency
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version"

//Koin
implementation "org.koin:koin-core:$koin_version"
implementation "org.koin:koin-androidx-scope:$koin_version"
implementation "org.koin:koin-androidx-viewmodel:$koin_version"

//firebase
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.0.0')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore-ktx'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:18.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.3.0'
implementation "androidx.browser:browser:1.3.0"

}
```

But it is not working. I also tried uploading images using for loop but that also was not behaving right way. How can i fix this problem? Please suggest me.

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: @ChristianB downloaded urls are not storing in firebase database.

Comment: So which function is not working? Did you Debug your code? Is there any error thrown?

Comment: Yes I debug my code and ain't getting any error .Sometimes this code works fine idk how and sometimes not. Am i doing it right way? . Also I'm not able to hide my progress bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
private lateinit var uid: String
suspend fun uploadData(dataMap: HashMap<String, String>, imagePaths: Array<Uri?>) {
    uid = Firebase.auth.currentUser!!.uid
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        dataMap["selfie"] = getUrl(imagePaths[0]!!, true)
        dataMap["adhaar pic"] = getUrl(imagePaths[1]!!, false)
        Firebase.firestore.document("Users Data/$uid").set(dataMap).await()
    }
}
private suspend fun getUrl(path: Uri, forGallery: Boolean): String {
    val fileName = if (forGallery) "gallery" else "camera"
    val ref = Firebase.storage.getReference("images/$uid/$fileName")
    ref.putFile(path).await()
    return ref.downloadUrl.await().toString()
}
```

then if that doesn't throw an exception the upload was successful

```
val uploadResponse = try {
    uploadData(...)
    "success"
} catch (e: Exception) {
    "failure"
}
```

Comment: Is there any await() method in Firebase?. I never heard about it.

Comment: [await](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-play-services/kotlinx.coroutines.tasks/com.google.android.gms.tasks.-task/await.html) is part of kotlin coroutines

Comment: No I'm getting "Unresolved reference: await" error. I know await is a part of coroutines but it's not working on firebase reference..

Comment: It works in my projects. Copy and paste my code. It should work unless you have an old version of kotlin (<1.3)

Comment: you can also try to import it manually `import kotlinx.coroutines.tasks.await`

Comment: Bro I'm using  (ext.kotlin_version = "1.4.21") kotlin version and it still showing me error when i import the package.

Comment: Are you using the ktx version of firestore? `com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore-ktx`

Comment: Are you sure you copied the code correctly? I pasted it in my project and dont get any unresolved reference

Comment: i checked my code two times. i copied it properly.

Comment: I can't understand what is happening. [Here](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/integration/kotlinx-coroutines-play-services/src/Tasks.kt) is the implementation of `await`. You can copy the code and create your own "await" function

Comment: Your code works but i still not able to import kotlinx.coroutines.tasks package.. I had to manually import my custom await function..

Comment: Actually you didn't tell me to import "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-play-services:1.4.2" . I add it in my gradle and now your code is working fine .

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was included in the standard library. I have `org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.4.2`.